# Why do I not have to return "average" each time before proceeding to run through the loop again?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, return

I am learning C and currently looking at multidimensional arrays, and I do not understand why I don't need to return the value of "average" before proceeding through the loop again with the *new* average that is made through each iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int grades[2][5];
    float average;
    int i;
    int j;

    grades[0][0] = 80;
    grades[0][1] = 70;
    grades[0][2] = 65;
    grades[0][3] = 89;
    grades[0][4] = 90;

    grades[1][0] = 85;
    grades[1][1] = 80;
    grades[1][2] = 80;
    grades[1][3] = 82;
    grades[1][4] = 87;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        average = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            average += grades[i][j];
        }

        average /= 5.0;
        printf("The average marks obtained in subject %d is: %.2f\n", i, average);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the second for loop, it starts by using `average = 0` which I understand, but as it goes through the iterations and `average` starts to increase (0+80, 80 + 70, 150 + 65, etc...), why do I not need to return this new average value and how does the program know to use this *new* value of average the next time it goes through the loop?

Why does it not just keep using `average = 0` for each iteration?

Comment: There is no "new" variable `average`. In the outer for loop you just reuse the same variable `average`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you may be getting your loops mixed up. See that the first loop, (for i) first sets average = 0, and then executes the second loop.

The second loop (for j) adds several values to average, not caring what the starting value is; average is being edited IN PLACE. (`average +=` means go find where average lives and change it).

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
|        average = 0;
|
|        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
|        |    average += grades[i][j];
|        |  }
|
|        average /= 5.0;
|        printf("The average marks obtained in subject %d is: %.2f\n", i, average);
|    }
```

The second loop doesn't care what average was before, and doesn't care that it is inside the first loop. It may help you to follow the code stepping in a debugger.

Maybe it would also help to note that 'average' is DECLARED way up at the start of main. In other languages `average = 0` can declare a variable average, but not in C. We need the 'float' or other type to declare a new variable. All mentions of average in your code are referring to the same object - the average declared at the start of main.

Comment: It might be that I'm mixing things up and I'm reading "average = 0" as declaring a variable named average instead of setting a starting point for average to begin within the loops (...right?), like you said. I'm not very familiar with C, but I've used it in the past so I might just be complicating things since it's been a while.

I also understand that average is then being edited in place, but how is it/where is it that the new value of average is being 'saved' to then act as the new starting value for the following iteration?

Comment: `average = 0` does not declare the variable. It just puts `0` into the variable which has been declared here: `float average;`

Comment: @Jabberwocky has it correct, in C, declarations start with a type: `float average;`. The other mentions of `average` in your example all refer to this same variable.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally the outer `for` sets the average value in each iteration to 0 again but the internal `for` iterates over one "line" of your array until it jumps out to the outer loop again.
As suggested by [Evan Benn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3936601/evan-benn) you should check the execution step-wise.

You will more or less see these values getting stored in `average`

```
//startup skipped
entering outer for i=0
    average = 0
        entering inner for j=0
              average = 0 + 80
        j = 1
              average = 80 + 70
        ... j = 2,3,4
              average = 150 + 85 + 89 + 90
        exiting inner loop, average is now
        average = 414
now code enters the outer for loop with i = 1
      average = 0 <-- here the outer for loop is resetting the value to 0 again
```

Comment: thank you for the help everyone, I understand it now. I'm definitely reading too far into certain things only to complicate them but it makes sense now.

Comment: Cool, please remember to mark the question as answered so other users can also profit :-)

Comment: Hey sorry about that! I tried to mark it as answered on my computer but it wouldn’t change the check mark to green so I didn’t know if it had gone through or not. I just did it on my phone, though, so hopefully it worked properly :)